# How to take in consideration the category of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

*In this script I want to put an additional condition according to the category ID or category name; How can I do it ?
in the syntax "else"
The catégory name is pinel ans the id is number 3
Thanks for your help
Maxwell*

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$bots = array(
    'google' => array('209.85.128','66.102.0','72.14.208','216.239.48','74.125.0','72.14.192','64.233.176','64.233.160','74.125.64','216.239.32','74.125.128','72.14.240','209.85.160','70.32.128','66.249.64','209.85.192','199.223.232','192.178.0','192.158.28','173.255.112','173.194.0','172.253.0','172.217.0','142.250.0','108.59.80','108.177.0'),
    'yahoo' => array('209.131.62','209.131.32','8.12.144','98.139.204','98.139.144','98.139.0','98.137.63','98.137.62','98.137.128','98.137.0','98.136.50','98.136.0','98.136.0','76.13.6','76.13.222','76.13.220','76.13.218','76.13.216','76.13.210','76.13.128','76.13.0','69.147.96','69.147.87','69.147.83','69.147.80','69.147.76','69.147.64','69.147.64','68.180.211','68.180.208','68.180.206','68.180.195','68.180.184','68.180.144','67.195.42','67.195.0','67.195.0','50.85.0','208.71.40','208.67.67','208.67.64','184.165.0'),
    'bing' => array('65.52.104','65.52.108','65.55.24','65.55.52','65.55.55','65.55.213','65.55.217','131.253.24','131.253.46','40.77.167','199.30.27','157.55.16','157.55.18','157.55.32','157.55.36','157.55.48','157.55.109','157.55.110','157.55.110','157.56.92','157.56.93','157.56.94','157.56.229','199.30.16','207.46.12','207.46.192','207.46.195','207.46.199','207.46.204','157.55.39')    
);

if($ip==$bots){
  true;
}else{
  header('Location: https://www.google.fr');
}
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like that if it is a bot, the bot continues on the page, if it is a visitor , and that visitor clicked on a post in the category "pinel" or ID3 then it is redirected to http://www.google.fr if the visitor clicked on a post in the category "scpi" or ID4 it will be redirected to http://www.yahoo.fr

Excuse me but my English is very 
poor

Thanks for your help
Max